# Уникальные значения в поле json (mysql)

Tags: mysql, json

Доброго времени суток.

Возник такой вопрос. Есть поле типа JSON, в нем массив объектов, например:
`[{"id": 1, "val": 10212}, {"id": 2, "val": 210212}, {"id": 1, "val": 210213}]`

Возможно ли средствами БД проверить уникальность id для записи при добавлении или изменении? Очень желательно без триггеров, с ними и сам могу )
Да, массив может быть огромный, потому варианты типа виртуального поля SET тоже не то, т.к. ограничение в 255 элементов.

Приведенный выше пример некорректен, т.к. два объекта с одним id

Спасибо.

Comment: А версия MySQL какая ? надеюсь у вас json пишется в колонку с типом "JSON" ? если так, то посмотрите как с этим типом работают групповые функции, вроде group_concat

Comment: Спасибо, что-то про них и забыл

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете генерируемую колонку, с типом хранения STORED

```
ALTER TABLE `you_table` ADD COLUMN `id_from_json` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`you_json_column_name` ->> '$.id') STORED NOT NULL;
```

и вешаете уникальный индекс, на данную колонку

```
ALTER TABLE `you_table` ADD UNIQ KEY `my_key_name`(`id_from_json`);
```